# Name of American horror movie: At the end of the movie, the monster, ape gives birth to a child

Tags: story-identification, movie

Name of American horror movie: At the end of the movie, the monster/ape gives birth to a child in a sewer. You see the monster/ape get shot above ground and the camera pans to the sewer there you the newborn. Hinting that the hunt is not over.
It's not a crocodile, it's an older movie from perhaps the 70's or early 80's.

Comment: “It’s not a crocodile, it’s an older movie...”. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: 99% of all horror movies end with hinting that the hunt is not over, so that doesn't narrow it down a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be ["V"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(franchise)) the television show? I remember a scene that showed stuff like afterbirth in sewers at the end of an episode. The "It's not a crocodile" line actually made me think of this. I'm not sure how to find specific episode plots online though.